# cloudera manager 5.4 installation freeze java oracle jdk on ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, failed-installation

Im installing cloudera 5.4 in ubuntu 14.04. When installation wizard starts and reaches installation of java section (part 2 of installation wizard) it freezes and the window turns gray. I wait for a long time but nothing happens so i close the window and stop the installation wizard. Then in order to re-run installation wizard i do

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/share/cmf /var/lib/cloudera* /var/cache/yum/cloudera*
```

But next time i run installation wizard it stops at the same stage. How to fix this?
Because i use java on other programs as well I have as first priority openjdk 7 when i do update-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your JAVA_HOME in and remove your openjdk from PATH  the terminal session from which you'll start the install process.

The installer will first install an oracle JDK to and keep on installing the rest of the cluster.

Don't forget the installer have to download about 4GB of data to perform the complete installation. It starts to download just after the Oracle JDK install and may appear to be en standby when it's actually downloading its subprograms